# Draw nodes according to (X,Y) coordinates? Zest

Tags: eclipse, zest

Can anybody help me please?
I should create a graph to display the nodes positions using eclipse. The positions are given as (X,Y) coordinates. Is this possible to do using Zest?
Or can you recommend other tool? (Note that I'm using eclipse RCP for other parts of the user interface)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the (X,Y) coordinates, Zest would not help you a lot, as it is centered around the concept of automatic layouting which does not work well with existing coordinates (however, it is possible to write a domain-specific layout algorithm that works with this input).

My opinion is that if supporting dragging of nodes (and possibly zooming) is a requirement, go and use Zest, in the end it will help you a lot. However, if you only need to draw a static graph without complex user interaction, I suggest drawing it by hand using either an SWT Canvas or Draw2d.